# Password protect a folder

Tags: windows, security, passwords, file-permissions

What are the available options for password protecting a folder? I'm talking about requiring a password to actually access the folder, not just user access rights. Is the third-party software out there secure and stable? What are the recommendations?

Comment: This is a great question (I just asked and almost duplicate myself). Could someone with the required rep re-tag this as windows XP and Vista? Then it is a little bit less specific and the accepted answer still holds.

Comment: I have retagged to a generic Windows tag

Comment: oops, just retagged to windows-xp windows-vista...sorry didn't see the comment

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[My Lockbox™](http://www.fspro.net/my-lockbox/)** is security software enabling you to password protect any folder on your computer.

The protected folder (lockbox) is hidden from any user and application of your system, including Administrator and System itself. It is impossible to access the lockbox, not only from the local computer, but also from the net.

The program is extremely easy to use. You can set the lockbox location and the password during the setup procedure. After the setup is done, lockbox will be hidden and locked until you enter the valid password.

**[Folder Lock](http://download.cnet.com/Folder-Lock/3000-2092_4-10063343.html)** is a Windows program to encrypt or password protect files, folders, removable drives, partitions, USB sticks, etc. In encryption mode it uses the strong 256-bit [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) encryption algorithm to encrypt objects on the fly. In lock mode files, folders and drives are not encrypted, but protected with a password.

*Folder Lock is shareware ($39.95), try before you buy.*

**[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)** and **[FreeOTFE](http://www.freeotfe.org/)** are powerful (and free) alternatives, but it might be an overkill for what you have in mind. They don't encrypt separate folders, but rather an entire filesystem (either a file-based "volume" or a whole disk).

Comment: I am a fan of truecrypt(additional + because it's free).  Now that you have an encrypted drive you can use subst to put the "drive" where a folder should be...might take a couple more steps, but it's a free solution that just works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows 7 Ultimate or Enterprise, I would suggest encrypting a partition with the built-in-tool [BitLocker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker) and storing your folder within that partition. You can also use a USB drive for that purpose.

I somehow don't trust third-party software with something as important as encryption. I usually avoid them and suggest against using them.

Answer (score 0):

**[PC Security™](http://www.tropsoft.com/pcsecurity/)**

> PC Security™ is the ultimate in computer security, offering multiple locking systems for the windows environment and internet. Lock files, monitor programs activities, even detect intruders! PC Security offers flexible and complete password protection, "Drag and Drop" support, plus many other handy features. All together, an incredible security package.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not 100% about actually password-protecting a folder, you could [zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) or [rar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR) the folder and password-protect it. Alternatively, I could recommend [TrueCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt) which has already been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Private Disk](http://www.dekart.com/products/encryption/private_disk/). It creates a virtual disk inside your system, encrypting it with [AES-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Description_of_the_cipher). The program is extremely easy to use.

Although it doesn't password protect a folder, I think it is a better choice.

The problem with the "password protected folder" paradigm is that such software needs to somehow integrate into [Windows Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) (otherwise the protected folder wouldn't appear as a folder). Besides that, it means that it will only work with Windows Explorer or some built-in file browser.

This imposes some constraints, rendering other programs unable to interact with the protected folder.

Private Disk's approach is fully transparent. Any program will be able to work with the encrypted volume as if it were a regular one.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately Windows 7 does not seem to support password protection of folders. This only appears to be possible through Windows authentication, i.e. changing the security permissions of the folder to only be accessible to certain users.

See [this article](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/smb-security/articles/43778.aspx) for more information.

Alternatively, you could use a third-party application to protect it. There are plenty of these floating around on Google :)

Comment: -1: He was specifically asking for third-party software.

Comment: read the question again buddy..