# How can I password protect a folder in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Password protect a folder](https://superuser.com/questions/103565/password-protect-a-folder)

For example: I store my payslips in digital form on my computer. How can I prevent someone who has legitimate access to the computer from accessing this folder?

I know about password protected archives and the like, I would just make life easier if I could protect a whole folder.

Thanks

Comment: I saw that question. It was tagged with windows-7 so I did not look further. The accepted answer there will work. Hope that does not change.

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of truecrypt. Now that you have an encrypted drive you can use subst to put the "drive" where a folder should be...might take a couple more steps, but it's a free solution that just works.

more info here:
http://www.truecrypt.org/
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-a-drive-letter-to-a-folder-the-easy-way-in-windows/

Comment: Truecrypt is great for things like this.