# set a password to a file in windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, security, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Password protect a folder](https://superuser.com/questions/103565/password-protect-a-folder)

Is there a way to set a password to a text file in Windows Vista i.e. when I try to open the file, it should prompt me for the password? do I need a third party software for this? if so, any recommendations please (including free ones)?

Comment: I know, not an exact, exact duplicate, but close enough, as you would have to put in a "container" of some kind, in order to protect it..

Answer (score 0):

Password protecting of folders is not supported on Windows NT (i.e XP, Vista, 7) unless you zip them. Right click a folder, then "send to > compressed folder". Now open the zip file, you will find an option under file> "add a password".

If you do not want to zip your file, you will require third party software like this [one](http://www.darfuns.com/folder-lock/).

Comment: The ZIP encryption algorithm is so weak it's worse than nothing. (AFAIK, Windows doesn't yet support AES for ZIP archives.)

Answer (score 0):

Try Izarc: http://www.izarc.org/

You can save your files in a ZIP file and add a password. The same software can be used to open the file as well.