# Password protect any folder without any third party software?

Tags: windows, password-protection

Just wanted to know, is it possible to password protect any confidential folder without any third party software?

I am using Windows 7 x86 Professional Edition. But the folder i need to protect could be accessed in XP/Vista/7

Comment: What operating system are you using, romilnagrani? When you edit your question, you should add a tag for that OS as well.

Comment: Question updated!

Comment: If you find you can't do it *without* third-party software, here is a question asking if you can do it *with* third-party software: [Password protect a folder](http://superuser.com/questions/103565/password-protect-a-folder)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in feature for "password protection" in the usual sense. (Any suggestions to create a password-protected "compressed folder" should be ignored due to the incredibly weak "security" of ZIP 2.0 encryption.)

However, recent Windows versions (XP Pro, Vista Business/Enterprise/Ultimate, 7 Pro/Enterprise/Ultimate) support [Encrypted File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_File_System) (more commonly EFS). Right-click a file or folder, open *Properties → Advanced*, and enable *Encrypt contents*.

In EFS, files are encrypted using a certificate associated with your Windows user account, and your Windows password is used to protect the certificate. If another user is logged in, or if you lose your certificate, the file cannot be accessed. (Win 7 prompts you to make a backup of the certificate; in other versions, you can export it through `certmgr.msc`.) It's also possible to add several users' certificates to the same file.

Comment: Without understanding how EFS works one should not use it. Otherwise this will earlier or later result in data loss because of encrypted data that can not be decrypted anymore (lost EFS key).

Comment: @Robert: The exact same thing applies to all encryption tools. Windows prompts you several times to back up the key.

Comment: But in EFS the key is automatically generated and a lot of users do not realize that there is a key and that this key is gone for example if the re-install Windows.

Comment: @Robert: Windows 7 displays the key generation UI to the user – and like I just said twice, repeatedly prompts the user to make a backup of that key.

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder, name it, then open it. Create a new text document, name it, then type the following or copy and paste it:

```
cls  
@ECHO OFF  
title Folder Private  
if EXIST "HTG Locker" goto UNLOCK  
if NOT EXIST Private goto MDLOCKER  
:CONFIRM  
echo Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N)  
set/p "cho=>"  
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK  
if %cho%==y goto LOCK  
if %cho%==n goto END  
if %cho%==N goto END  
echo Invalid choice.  
goto CONFIRM  
:LOCK  
ren Private "HTG Locker"  
attrib +h +s "HTG Locker"  
echo Folder locked  
goto End  
:UNLOCK  
echo Enter password to unlock folder  
set/p "pass=>"  
if NOT %pass%== PASSWORD_GOES_HERE goto FAIL  
attrib -h -s "HTG Locker"   
ren "HTG Locker" Private  
echo Folder Unlocked successfully  
goto End  
:FAIL  
echo Invalid password
goto end
:MDLOCKER
md Private
echo Private created successfully
goto End
:End
```

Then change the `PASSWORD_GOES_HERE` to anything you want – it'll be your password. Save the text, then change the `TEXT DOCUMENT.txt` to `Locker.bat`.

If you can't see the extension of the folder, go to *Organise* wich will be in the left coner of the folder, then go to *Folder and Search Options*. Go to *View* and uncheck the *Hide extension for known file types*. Click *Apply* and you will see the extension.

Double click the `Locker.bat`. This will create a folder called `Private`. Then put the things you want to lock in it and go back and open the `Locker.bat`.

If you want to lock the folder type `y` then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The `Private` file will disappear. If you want to open the private file, open the `Locker.bat`, type your password then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

*Note:* This is *not* the place to store confidential information, such as medical records, financial information or passwords. This is not the best place to hide things from an IT professional, but it should work against newbies or people with intermediate computer skills.