# How to protect a folder with a password

Tags: windows-7

Does anyone know of a way to simply encrypt a folder with a password, without hiding the folder??

I dont want to have to mount or dismount a volume, or unlock a folder everytime i want to access it. I want the folder on my desktop, viewable, just with a password when someone tries to enter it.

I have looked around the web but can't find anything(free) that fits. Very frustrating.

Working on Windows7 64 bit.

Anything??

Comment: [Password protect a folder](http://superuser.com/questions/103565/password-protect-a-folder)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could think of is to password a zipped folder placed on the desktop. Anything else is a lot of hassle for not much gain.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)

Main features:

```
Creates a virtual encrypted disk within a file and mounts it as a real disk.

Encrypts an entire partition or storage device such as USB flash drive or hard drive.

Encrypts a partition or drive where Windows is installed (pre-boot authentication).

Encryption is automatic, real-time (on-the-fly) and transparent.

Parallelization and pipelining allow data to be read and written as fast as if the drive was not encrypted.

Encryption can be hardware-accelerated on modern processors.

Provides plausible deniability, in case an adversary forces you to reveal the password:

Hidden volume (steganography) and hidden operating system.
```