# How to create a password protected working directory that can be accessed by my supervisor and I, as well as by Latex compiler?

Tags: windows, security, passwords, latex, home-directory

The main idea is I want to limit the access to my Latex files which are located in my folder in Lab server.
Due to Lab regulation, I cannot use online cloud service, e.g., Overleaf.

I am open to any possibility to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Do you have something like a gitlab server in your lab?

Comment: I am not sure. Let's assume I do not have it. I do not mind to create it if it does not require installation or admin access.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz well, it is only available on linux. I do not think it is possible for to do it. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html

Comment: Ok, if you don't have such a thing, go talk to your admins. Having a version control system in your lab only has advantages and allows you to easily share your work with your colleagues.

Comment: (there is also a version of overleaf for self-hosting)

Comment: Am I missing something here?  Why can this not be solved by simple group permissions in Windows?  You will also need to run the Latex compiler as someone in that group (of course)..  From what I read from your request, this is not rocket science as some of the other answers are implying.  You just need a share.. easier if the machine and accounts are part of the same domain.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, I agree with you. I also think this should not be a complex execution. I just do not know how.  before posting it here, I was looking solutions like https://superuser.com/questions/103565/password-protect-a-folder. My limitation is I do not have admin rights. I will take a look about setting up group permissions in Windows.

Comment: *SOMEONE* has admin rights.  They need to help you with this (due to permissions and not intellect) ;)  It sounds like someone is just trying to do their job.. it also sounds like someone ELSE is NOT doing their job.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, relax. I just cannot explain more about my situation here. I can only simply mention here that I do not have it and would like to have this functionality without needing to have admin rights.

Comment: OK.. ok.. I get it.  It makes me hot headed as I have been in this position before.  Good luck sir.